# Python: kill all processes of a pool

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, application-pool, daemons

I have a function `foo()` that creates multiple objects. This function is called several times during the run of my progam. In order to speed up my code, I want to make `foo()` create a set of processes, that calculate the new objects in parallel.

```
def foo(self):
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    self.nodes = pool.map(self._create_node, self.args)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

 def _create_node(self, args):
        n = Node(args)
        return n
```

This is working theoretically, but after a few calls of `foo()` my computer freezes. I think the processes do not get killed after my call in `foo()`, although I call close and join. What am I doing wrong?

If I kill the program from the terminal, I get this error:

```
->File "threading.py", line 1070, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
    elif lock.acquire(block, timeout):

KeyboardInterrupt:
```

### Edit

To add some more information, when I start the program it is initialy running fast, but slows down over the time. As the program slows down, the RAM consumption rises, exceeding my RAM and filling the Swap. Without the multiprocessing, you don't notice any RAM consumption at all, as the program is really small. `htop` shows only 1 up to 4 processes running at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
def foo(self):
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        result = pool.map_async(self._create_node, self.args)
        try:
             self.nodes = result.get(300) #get the result or throws a timeout exception after 300 seconds
        except:
             pool.terminate()
```

You don't need to close() the pool as it is called automatically

edited timeout

Comment: I tried your code, but this resulted in the same problem. `htop` shows me pages full of my python executions.

Comment: I tried your edit, but I can't kill the process until I received a result. How can I kill the process after it finished its computations?

Comment: just remove the optional timeout in get() and call pool.terminate() after this (not in the except-block). but i recommend to set a timeout

Comment: Now my computer is no more freezing. Still the computation slows down extremly the more often `foo()` has been called.

Comment: do you call foo() asynchronously?

Comment: you can restrict the processes "with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2) as pool:" .....

Comment: I call foo() sequential. The only multiprocessing in my program happens inside foo().

Comment: how many instances do you create? maybe you run out of ram... i think, that's all i can say about it

Comment: htop shows me 3 instances of my python script. Those use about 3GB of my RAM, this is way too much, compared to how much the single threaded program uses.